# Как отключить дублирование миниатюр, при загрузке в библиотеку?

Tags: wordpress

Возможно ли в вордпресе отключить создание **всех миниатюр** при загрузке изображения напрямую через

> Библиотеку файлов

Но если загружается изображение через страницу, магазин или запись, то что бы миниатюры работали.

Comment: Если немного выучить ВП, то подобные вопросы отпадут как глупые. А пока просто усвой что не нужно так делать. Особенно без понимания назначения миниатюр.

Comment: @SeVlad в смысле отпадут вопросы, ну я еще раз напишу здесь для твоего понимание зачем это нужно сделать, когда ты создаешь запись в блоге, или страницу, ты загружаешь изображения, и создаются миниатюры. Так вот зачем миниатюры от вукомерс будут создавать копии для страниц и записей?! Это все ведет к забитой памяти. Если ты считаешь что эти процессы не нужно оптимизировать, то сорян.

Comment: Миниатюры создаются не "для WC" или для любого др плагина, а для САЙТА. И могут показываться там, где ты даже не представляешь.  Вот этого ты и не понимаешь.  что хуже - ты не понимаешь что такое медиатека ВП. А оптимизировать нужно *графику*, а не "процессы", в которых ты не понимаешь. Прощаю, ок :)

Comment: @SeVlad Ты ошибаешься, я это понимаю и с этим сталкивался, но я четко осознаю и понимаю нужную мне задачу.